# ADB shows the same device multiple times - "Offline" and "Device"

Tags: android, adb

ADB shows me the same device multiple times:
XXXXX offline
XXXXX device

When i'm trying to close the usb port it shows me only the offline device:
XXXXX offline.

If i'm trying to kill-server and start-server everything works and i see only the
connected device:
XXXXX device.

Is there is anyway to throw/clean the "voodoo" offline device without doing kill-server or to kill the adb.exe process?

Comment: i know there's some bug in the sdk. Perhaps update to the latest release and try.

Comment: i tried to use the latest ADB - 1.0.31 but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue... ended up running a batch file at application start, which kills the adb.

Comment: I know i can kill the adb but i don't want to do it.

Comment: There is another option besides killing the ADB or kill-server?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem but the following things helped me

1. adb kill-server
2. Turn off USB debug and turn it on and connect via USB.
3. Restart the device.

Most of the times the above steps helped me.